# Eclipse Java Memory Error: Heap. Developing in Android with Phonegap.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, cordova

I have a Android App I have developed, It has been created from a successful ios App that was released and works fine. On one device it works correctly, no errors and does not crash. However on another device (newer, newer version of Android, faster processor) it crashes. Here are the memory errors when it crashes.

[image]

The app is designed to take a picture and to then use that picture as the background for a canvas, then a screen shot is taken. I can go through this process once, but then if I repeat the process and take another picture, the application crashes on exit of the camera API for the second time. And displays these errors. The application is Developed in Eclipse using Phonegap and Jquery mobile. I am unsure which parts of my code I should post to help this problem, but please feel free to ask if you feel some may be relevant.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you review my post on why we run out of memory on PhoneGap Android apps:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/07/change-to-camera-code-in-phonegap-190.html

You may find some tips when you use the camera.getPicture() command. Other than that I'm currently working on fixing some of these Camera issues by bringing everything in house instead of firing a camera intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make such trick.... To set picture as background use...

```
   public void setbg(){
 String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "scm_pic.jpg";
 Resources res = getResources();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
 BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
 View view = findViewById(R.id.container);
 view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
}
```

And then when you don't need this picture or want to @Override onPause methods or to switch another activity use...

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
 if (view.getBackground() != null) {
 view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
 }
 if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
     for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
     unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
     }
 ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
  }
}
```

To use it in @Override use for examole...

```
unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.container));
System.gc();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use camera means Destination type must in FILE_URL in android. because DATA_URI gives base64 string so it gives out of memory error sometime. First u get URL from camera then Convert base64 format using filesystem concepts...